# Python3 Error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.8'

Tags: calculation

im trying to make a calculation script with python but im running into this problem:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.8'

Im trying to ask a user for an input that is in numbers like 2000 but when the input contains a ',' or '.' it will output that error.

This is the code:

```
Buiten = int(input("Buiten: "))
Binnen = int(input("Binnen: "))
DikteF = int(input("Dikte: "))
Sortle = int(input("Soortelijk gewicht: "))

inputs = Buiten,Binnen,DikteF,Sortle
Pi = 3.14

R1 = Buiten / 2
R2 = Binnen / 2

UD1 = Pi*R1/1000*R1/1000
UD2 = Pi*R2/1000*R2/1000

Tpv = UD1 - UD2

Ltr = Tpv * DikteF

Srt = Ltr * Sortle


print("")
print("Uitwendige Diameter = ",(round(UD1, 3)),"m²")
print("Inwendige Diameter = ",(round(UD2, 3)),"m²")
print("Product Oppervlak = ",(round(Tpv, 3)), "m²")
print("")
print("Inhoud in L = ",(round(Ltr, 3)),"Liters")
print("Totaal gewicht = ",(round(Srt, 3), "Kilos" ))
print("")
os.system("pause")
```

while True:
try:
Bereken()
except:
print("Fout: Gebruik alleen cijfers.")
time.sleep(4)
Bereken()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python returns an error since it is expecting an *integer* value as string to convert to integer. However, when passing decimals, the attempt to convert to integer fails since they are not integers.

if you are going to insert either integers or decimals, use `float`

```
Buiten = float(input("Buiten: "))
Binnen = float(input("Binnen: "))
DikteF = float(input("Dikte: "))
Sortle = float(input("Soortelijk gewicht: "))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine now.